# Emberjs - Model not change boolean value when send PUT request

Tags: ember.js

Good morning !!

We have problems with requests when send changed boolen values on the model.

When load the model from the server, the value in the model is false, but, when update the boolean to true value, the request not sends true, but sends false.

router:

```
actions: {
    save:function() {
      let post = this.controller.get("model");
      console.log(post.get("isPost")); // logs **true**
      post.save().then(() => { // request {"description":"The Post","isPost":**false**}
          this.transitionTo('posts');
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
}
```

model:

```
import Model from './default';
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default Model.extend({
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  isPost: DS.attr('boolean')
});
```

I tryed to set boolean to true direct on the model, but it sends the same wrong request, send false instead true...

airline.set('isPost',true);
airline.save....

Comment: Why are you using `import Model from './default';` instead of `DS.Model`?

Comment: What is your backend returning as a response to your save?

Answer (score 0):

To set a default value to an attribute, use something like this :

```
isPost: DS.attr('boolean', {defaultValue: false})
```